# How to put different styles on two identical <cite> elements?

Tags: html, css

I have this

```
<p>
     <cite>One</cite><cite>Two</cite>
</p>
```

is there a way in css to say that the first cite is going to be bold and the second italics, **without editing the above code**?

Comment: you should make the topic title more descriptive and specific to your actual question.

Comment: You're trying to use a drill and hammer to fix a camera...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With CSS3, you should be able to accomplish this with the following style:

```
cite:nth-child(1) { font-weight: bold; }
cite:nth-child(2) { font-style: italic; }
```

CSS3 is pretty poorly supported at the moment, so check the browsers you decide to support.

Answer (score 6):

```
p > cite { font-weight: bold }
p > cite + cite { font-style: italic }
```

But beware that it won't work in IE6. You might want to use jquery to apply css3 rules in ie6. There is also a script called [IE7](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/), but it's a bit slow.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the :first-child pseudo selector although it is not cross-browser friendly.

```
p cite:first-child { font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; }
cite { font-style: italics; }
```

Answer (score 5):

There are ways to do it with CSS, but it won't be compatible with IE6.  As long as you're okay with that, you could do this:

```
p cite {
    font-weight: bold; 
}

p cite + cite {
    font-style: italic; 
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The reason this works is because '+' selects the sibling of any given cite.  Since sibling relationships only go forwards in the DOM, you'll only select the second (or nth, where n > 1) cite tag.

Unfortunately + doesn't work with IE6.

Comment: All of the cite tags in a paragraph will be bold with this approach.

Comment: (And the second and successive cites would be italicized, of course).

Answer (score 1):

```
p cite:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
p cite:last-child {
    font-style: italic;
}
```